# put cursor after setHint TextView android

Tags: android, textview, android-cursor

I try to put my cursor in a TextView after the setHint.
Here is my code, I tried to use setFocus, setSelection and it does not work.

```
if (ctrl instanceof TextView)
    {
        TextView ctrlCtrl = (TextView)ctrl;
        ctrlCtrl.setTextColor(textColor);
        ctrlCtrl.setTextSize(textSize);
        java.lang.String placeholder = getPlaceholder();
        if (!StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(placeholder))
        {
            ctrlCtrl.setHint(placeholder);
            int placeholderColorDefault = Color.argb(130, Color.red(textColor), Color.green(textColor), Color.blue(textColor));
            ctrlCtrl.setHintTextColor(getColorStyle(FieldStyle.PLACEHOLDER_COLOR, getColorStyle(FieldStyle.PLACEHOLDERTEXTCOLOR, placeholderColorDefault)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: In this way `hint` will work similar like `text` itself. Why you need such behavior?

Comment: This will be a bad user exp.

Comment: It is user request.